# Oracle won't start

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, startup

While it was working fine, I had to stop the server once. When trying to start Oracle using a script we have, I got the following error:

```
SQL> Connected to an idle instance.
SQL> ORA-01081: cannot start already-running ORACLE - shut it down first
SQL> Disconnected
```

Also when trying to start SQL Plus manually AS SYSDBA I get:

```
ERROR:
ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified
```

Using SQL Plus with other users, I get:

```
ERROR:
ORA-12537: TNS:connection closed
```

Any help appreciated ...

Comment: Have you tried restarting the machine itself?  I'm primarily a Windows guy - hence the "restart" advice.

Comment: Double check ORACLE_HOME and ORACLE_SID environment variables. Also look what Oracle processes are running and what messages are in alert log. I'm speaking from Linux experience.

Answer (score 1):

- 1st check contents of the ORACLE_SID and ORACLE_HOME variables. Even a trailing slash at the ORACLE_HOME path makes difference
- Locate files "alert_${ORACLE_SID}.log" and "listener.log", there you will find more information

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you are trying to run a script using crontab, all Oracle specific environment variables need to be set inside the script. It will not take values from .profile/.bash_profile files.

Looks like the ORACLE_SID and ORACLE_HOME variables are not set

Answer (score -3):

Try the following command:

```
startup force
```

Comment: Typically you should add more details to your answer.  Even though you may be correct, further details will help the OP and future visitors to understand why.